# Existence of a subspace with given characteristics

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

My Algebra books gives the following exercises:

Let f be a reflexive $(f(u,w)=0 $\Leftrightarrow$ f(w,u)=0)$ bilinear form on a vector space $V$ $(\dim V=n)$.

Let $U \subset V$ and

(1) $f$ is symmetric and non-degenerate on $U$

(2) $f$ is alternating on $U^\perp$ .

Show the existence of $U$.

I don't really see how I can prove this exercise. I tried to define a random subspace $U'$, on which $f$ is symmetric and non-degenerate. Then there should exist (I guess?) a subspace $W$ of the orthogonal complement of $U'$ with $U'\oplus W=X$ (direct sum). But is this even helpful?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: reflexive means $xRx$

Comment: According to the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119832/reflexive-bilinear-forms), either $U = V$ or $U=\{0\}$ (so $U^\perp = V$). But without that result, maybe you can mimic the Gram-Schmidt construction to get an orthogonal basis for $U$.

Comment: Or maybe Zorn's lemma

Comment: @MathFail The same word can have different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656213/bilinear-form-with-symmetric-perpendicular-relation-is-either-symmetric-or-ske/

Comment: Thank you! With the help of the linked questions/answers I was actually able to find a solution to my problem.